# How to control JCarousel Vertical Scroller speed?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

How to control JCarousel Vertical Scroller speed?

Answer (score 4):

Try `animation: 1600`. I think this will help you.
For example:

```
jQuery('#anyid').jcarousel({
    auto: 3,
    vertical: true,
    wrap: 'circular',
    scroll: 2,
    animation: 1600
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't a PHP question, but doing a quick google search I found the documentation on jcarousel.

[doc link](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)

Property to change it "animation".

> The speed of the scroll animation as string in jQuery terms ("slow" or
>   "fast") or milliseconds as integer
>   (See jQuery Documentation). If set to
>   0, animation is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Nice working it very helpful post found here. Smoothly scrolling images slider i changes
in coding and give them a new look...

jQuery('#anyid').jcarousel({
   scroll: 1,
        auto: 2,
        animation: 1500,
        wrap: 'last',
        initCallback: _init_carousel,
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null
});